# A UPGMA cluster in R with NoData values

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, vegan

I have a matrix of sites. I want to develop a UPGMA aglomerative cluster. I want to use R and the vegan library for that. My matrix has sites in which not all the variables were measured.

Following a similar matrix of data:

```
Variable 1;Variable 2;Variable 3;Variable 4;Variable 5
0.5849774671338231;0.7962161133598957;0.3478909861199184;0.8027122599553912;0.5596553797833573
0.5904142034898171;0.18185393432022612;0.5503250366728479;NA;0.05657408486342197
0.2265148074206368;0.6345513807275411;0.8048128547418062;0.3303602674038131;0.8924461773052935
0.020429460126217602;0.18850489885886157;0.26412619465769416;0.8020472793070729;NA
0.006945970735023677;0.8404983401121199;0.058385134042814646;0.5750066564897788;0.737599672122899
0.9909722313946067;0.22356808747617019;0.7290078902086897;0.5621006367587756;0.3387823531518016
0.5932907022602052;0.899773235815933;0.5441346748937264;0.8045695319247985;0.6183003409599681
0.6520679140573288;0.5419713133237936;NA;0.7890033752744002;0.8561828607592286
0.31285906479192593;0.3396351688936058;0.5733594373520889;0.03867689654415574;0.1975784885854912
0.5045966366726562;0.6553489439611587;0.029929403932252963;0.42777351534900676;0.8787135401098227
```

I am planing to do it with the following code:

```
library(vegan)
# env <- read.csv("matrix_of_sites.csv")
env.norm <- decostand(env, method = "normalize") # Normalizing data here
env.ch <- vegdist(env.nom, method = "euclidean")
env.ch.UPGMA <- hclust(env.ch, method="average")
plot(env.ch.UPGMA)
```

After I run the second line, I get this error:

```
Error in x^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I am not familiar with R, so I am not sure if this is due to the cells with no data. How can I solve this?

Comment: @gung : thanks for your suggestion. I included data to support a reproducible example.

Comment: I formatted the data for you.  You can check how it's done for future reference if you like. I notice there are 2 places where you had only 4 values & had back to back semicolons `;;`. I take those to be missing values; I put `NA`s there.  Edit that, if appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R does not think that data are numeric in your matrix, but at least some of them were interpreted as character variables and changed to factors. Inspect your data after reading int into R. If all your data are numbers, then `sum(env)` gives a numeric result. Use `str()` or `summary()` functions for detailed inspection.

From R's point of view, your data file has mixed formatting. R function `read.csv` assumes that items are separated by comma (`,`) and the decimal separator is period (`.`), and `read.csv2` assumes that items are separated by colon (`;`) and decimal separator is comma `,`. You mix these two conventions. You can read data formatted like that, but you may have to give both the `sep` and `dec` arguments.

If you get your data correctly in R, then `decostand` will stop with error: it does not accept missing values if you do not add `na.rm = TRUE`. The same also with the next `vegdist` command: it also needs `na.rm = TRUE` to analyse your data.

Comment: thanks for your help, and for Vegan! Setting `header = TRUE, dec = '.', sep = ',', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings='NA'` when calling decostand did the job.

Comment: I had a second question: I am applying cluster and PCA analysis in Q-mode: I am comparing sites (or objects, as L&L would say), not variables. My variables are disparate (e.g., precipitation, slope, imperviousness). Should I apply a normalization within variables before getting chord distances between sites?